# Suspect code indent for conditional statements

Tags: c, linux, for-loop, coding-style, putchar

currently I am working on C project and i faced the following error -

- 8-print_base16.c:11: WARNING: suspect code indent for conditional statements (8, 15)

related with Betty coding style.

This issue based on the following code snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/**
 * main - function or entry point
 * Return: Always 0 (success)
 **/
int main(void)
{
        char digit;

        for (digit = 0; digit <= 9; digit++)
        {
               putchar(digit + '0');
        }

        for (digit = 'a'; digit <= 'f'; digit++)
        {
                putchar(digit);
        }

        putchar('\n');
        return (0);
}
```

Can you help to resolve this problem please?

I have tried to write conditions so many times, but its again give the same result

Comment: I believe it expects the opening brace to come inline with the `for` statement. If not, check your leading tabs/spaces consistency

Comment: Did you accidentally use spaces for indentation on that line? Otherwise, it seems consistent with how I understand the Betty style (from a quick look - I have not used it myself).

Answer (score -1):

I have solved it, the problem is that i have some accidental space before putchar function on the first loop. Thanks who tried to to help.